# Rewrite product position save logic

Tags: category, position

I'm new to Magento and I'm trying to figure out how to change the product position save logic when you save a category. I would like it to auto increment by ten for each product so that when you're finished the first product has a position of 10, second 20, third 30 and so on. This would make it easy to place products between the first product (10) and second product (20) by setting the product position to 15.

Any pointers on where to start would be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Here is small code which help you to do ordering very fase ( direct database injection )

```
$sql = 'update catalog_category_product set position = "'.$i.'" where 
category_id = "'.$_REQUEST['catId'].'" and product_id = "'.$_REQUEST['cat'][1][$i].'"';
```

Comment: please add escaping to your code example, if someone puts this in a webserver he creates a big security hole.

Comment: we are using just be careful before use...